# How do I install graphics.py on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, python

I need to install [graphics.py](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) for class. How do I do that, and how do I install other [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) modules?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python version 3.4

Comment: Where did you find this graphics.py file? Please add a download link to your question

Comment: http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

to correct No module named Tkinter and _tkinter

```
sudo apt-get install tk-dev
cd /Python3.4.1 
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: -1 for "out of the blue" upstream Python local build. Why is it needed to compile your own Python here? Please clarify.

Comment: reinstall python3 really works on my Ubuntu 14.04.
I think .configure and install make python3 be configured for Tkinter

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a guide](http://cpsc110.umwblogs.org/installing-python-graphics-library/):

> Start at Zelle’s Python page at http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/.
>
> The graphics module is listed as *graphics.py. RIGHT-CLICK on the link and then select >Save Link As
>
> On a PC save the link in C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages
>
> On a Mac save the link in
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/site-packages/
>
> On Ubuntu save the link in
>
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 I tried to copy and paste it in usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages and usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages

Comment: Okay so then what happened?

Comment: When I use eclipse it doesn't import graphics

Comment: @user3485632 have you tried running the program without Eclipse?  Eclipse is really only decent for Java.

Comment: I've tried in Canopy aswell and got this error message: ImportError: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy your graphics.py copy in a python3 imported path:

```
sudo cp graphics.py /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/
```

Then the only dependency to install is Tkinter:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

To check that you can import your new module start a `python3` interpreter like this:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from graphics import *
>>>
```

You should not see any `ImportError` message.

Comment: I got two import errors  ImportError: No module name '_tkinter' and ImportError: No module name 'Tkinter'

Comment: I got this error when a run a command in `python` (2.x). Please be sure to run your script with a `python3` interpreter otherwise install `python-tk` for python2.x: `sudo apt-get install python-tk`

Comment: I am using the python 3 interpreter and both versions are installed, I also have this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/graphics.py", line 159, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for T

Comment: and Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/graphics.py", line 161, in <module>
    import Tkinter as tk
ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'

Comment: When I use python 2.7 I don't get any errors and inside python2.7/dist-packages I have virtualenv-1.11.6  and inside python3.4/dist-packages I only have graphics.py